# What's the difference between following two Prolog lists?

Tags: prolog

I'm kind of confused between the difference of the two following lists:

```
K = [1,2,3 | X].
```

and

```
K = [1,2,3,X].
```

The question in the book of Bratko is actually in the context of `conc`.

conc is defined as:

```
conc([], L, L).
conc([X|L1], L2, [X|L3]) :- conc(L1, L2, L3).
```

The actual question now is if in

```
conc([1,2,3], [X], L2).
```

L2 is the same list as K in the query   `K = [1,2,3|X].`

I don't think L2 and K are the same, but I'm not so sure how to explain it. L2 is the concatenation of two lists. K is the concatenation of something I'm not sure of with a variable X that can be filled in by a list...

Still learning Prolog, so forgive me if this is a 'stupid' question.

Comment: `conc([1,2,3],[X],[1,2,3,X])` and `conc([1,2,3],X,[1,2,3|X])` both hold. That's actually very visually intuitive, especially the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Prolog each list is either empty list (`[]`) or head and a tail (`[A | X]`). Head is first element and tail is rest of the list.

Examples:

- `[1]` is actually `[1 | []]`
- `[1, 2]` is `[1 | [2 | []]]`
- `[1,2,3 | [4, 5]]` is the same as `[1,2,3,4,5]` (which is different from 4-element list `[1,2,3,[4,5]]` ).

So in your example `L2` is `[1,2,3,X]`, which is four element list with last element `X`. Meanwhile `K` is `[1,2,3|X]` which is a lists which starts with `1,2,3` and than has all elements of `X`.

Following picture shows the difference between structures of `[1,2,3,X]` and `[1,2,3|X]`.
[image: [1,2,3,X] vs [1,2,3|X]]

Comment: So L2 and K are actually the same? Or is [1,2,3,X] not the same as [1,2,3|X]? Because I can easily write [1,2,3,X] as [1,2,3|X] I guess...

Comment: @LievenCardoen, no, you can write `[1,2,3,X]` as `[1,2,3|[X]]`.

Comment: It's probably too obvious for you... but I'm still not seeing the difference between [1,2,3|X] and [1,2,3|[X]]

Comment: @LievenCardoen, I've added a picture, maybe it can help a bit.

Comment: @LievenCardoen `X` is certainly not the same as `[X]`. Don't you see the brackets? `X` is a logical variable. `[X]` is a list of one element, which is a logical variable `X`.

Comment: Both lists can be same in a specific condition. When the first list is [1,2,3|X1] and the second one is [1,2,3,X2] (X's are distinct variables) then both are same if and only if X1 = [X2]. That is, the tail of the first list contains only the last element of the second one.

Comment: @LievenCardoen the important distinction is that in `[1,2,3,X]`, the value `X` represents a single, uninstantiated element of the list. The element may itself be a list as well, but it would in that case be a sublist. If `X` is `[4,5]` then `[1,2,3,X]` is `[1,2,3,[4,5]]`. In `[1,2,3|X]`, the value `X` must be a list and represents the rest or tail of the list `1, 2, 3, ...`, and it may be the empty list `[]`. If `X` is `[4,5]` then `[1,2,3|X]` is `[1,2,3|[4,5]]` or `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: Thx for all your help. One last question, if X = [], are the lists still different from each other? I guess you would then have [1,2,3,[]] and [1,2,3], so they would not be equal?

Comment: @LievenCardoen, when `X = []`, then in the first case you have `[1,2,3,[]]` which is a list of the 4 elements: `1`, `2`, `3`, `[]`. In the second case, you have `[1,2,3|[]]` which is equivalent to `[1,2,3]` since the syntax means "the elements `1`, `2`, `3`, with no tail or trailing elements".